# MPI runtime giving incorrect output

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi

I'm trying to test the total runtime using `MPI_Wtime()` however I'm getting incorrect outputs.

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int rank, size, len;
   double start, end, runtime;
   char name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];

   MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
   MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

   MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
   MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
   MPI_Get_processor_name(name, &len);
   start = MPI_Wtime();

   printf("Hello World! I am %d of %d on %s\n", rank, size, name);
   fflush(stdout);
   Sleep(1000);
   MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
   end = MPI_Wtime();

   MPI_Finalize();

   if (rank == 0)
   {
        runtime = end - start;
        printf("Start time = %d\n", start);
        printf("End time = %d\n\n", end);
        printf("Runtime = %d\n", runtime);
   }

   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

I get outputs like this:

> Hello World! I am 0 of 1 on test
>   Start time = 505400631
>   End time = 521122106
>
> Runtime = -1878261760
>   Press any key to continue .  .  .

I'm expecting to get seconds, but I'm getting these long outputs instead. Any idea why?

Comment: Next time you submit a question, please put in the actual text instead of an image with the output of your program. It's very hard to view that image in a lot of situations and it's much better to just have the real output.

Answer (score 2):

`MPI_Wtime()` returns a `double` and `start` , `end` and `runtime` are double. By doing `printf("Start time = %d\n", start);` you are printing `start` as an integer.

I complied your code using gcc (and replacing `Sleep` of `<Windows.h>` by `sleep` of `<unistd.h>`) and the following warning appears :

```
main.c:34:9: attention : format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘double’ [-Wformat]
```

The solution is to print these numbers as `double` :

```
 printf("Runtime = %g\n", runtime);
```

The `system("pause")` is not necessary and i think it would advisable to move `MPI_Finalize()` at the very end of your program, after the printing operations.